# No option of Android SDK Build-tools in Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file, android-sdk-2.3

I am new to Eclipse and I need to install Android SDK Build tools but it is not showing in the options that the Android SDK Manager has on display.

These are the only options that it is showing:

[image]

I need to install it to get the R.java file error to go away..What should be done?

Answer (score 0):

#### In the Android SDK Manager

Go to Tools > Options > Others - Check **"Force https:// ... sources to be fetched using http:// ...**"

This should allow you to connect to the Android repository if it was not connecting before.

Also make sure you click File > Reload after you do this, if the packages do not reload.

Comment: Tried that but I am getting the following errors:-

    Fetching http://dl-  
    ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml

    Fetched Add-ons List successfully
    Fetching URL: http://dl- 
    ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-9.xml
    Done loading packages.
    Fetching http://dl-  
    ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
    Failed to fetch URL http://dl- 
    ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: 
    Unknown Host proxy

Comment: Just a shot in the dark - Try running the SDK Manager as Administrator?